# Android 4 Color Gradient (Not linear)

Tags: android, xml, gradient

Was wondering if its possible to create a gradient like this one in either XML or programmatically:

[image]

I've seen plenty of answers on how to create a linear 4-color gradient, however that is not what I'm looking for as this a not linear gradient but rather a corner gradient. Where every corner is a different color.

Thank you!